# How to set an image from the gallery to UIButton background? Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a rounded button which represent a User Avatar. By clicking on this button I invoke an ImagePicker and then trying to set picked image to UIbutton.

**First I do this:**

```
@IBAction func choseAvatar(_ sender: Any) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self
    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    image.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Then this:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    userAvatar.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The image picked successfully, but there is a problem. The image is stretched down to the bottom of the screen. How to do it right?

[image]

**I also tried**

```
userAvatar.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
userAvatar.imageView?.image = pickedImage
```

**And:**

```
userAvatar.setImage(image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead set image try set-background image and if you are using auto layout check option clips to bound true and give aspect ration 1:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your constraints are set correctly for the imageView. Make sure you use AspectFit (or Fill if you have a fixed width and height), and make sure you have clipToBounds enabled.